# can pubsubclient connect over ssl using public certs?

Tags: publish-subscribe, esp32, mosquitto

I have an esp32 development board and I'm using the pubsubclient version 2.8 from this website here:

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/pubsubclient/

I also have a mosquitto broker set up and I'm using Let's Encrypt ssl to encrypt all traffic.  Commands like `mosquitto_sub -h my.server.com -u myuser -P mypass -p 7383 -t esp32/output` works fine (notice I did not need to specify any cert authorities and I changed the port number).

However, my esp32 pubsubclient can't seem to connect when my mosquitto broker uses SSL.  If I disable SSL on the mosquitto server, then everything works fine.  This is the code that my esp32 uses to connect to the mqtt server:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void mqtt_configure(const char* mqtt_server, int mqtt_port) {
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, mqtt_port);
}
void mqtt_connect(const char* mqtt_topic, const char* mqtt_user, const char* mqtt_pass) {
  listening_topic = String(mqtt_topic);
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("ESP32Client", mqtt_user, mqtt_pass)) {
      Serial.println("connected, subscribing to");
      Serial.println(mqtt_topic);
      // Subscribe
      client.subscribe(mqtt_topic);
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
void setup() {
  mqtt_configure("my.server.com", 7383);
  mqtt_connect("esp32/output", "myuser", "mypass");
}
```

Again this code works fine if my mosquitto server does not have SSL enabled.  But if I enable SSL, then the esp32 gives the `client.state()` value of `-2`, which is an error code that means failure to connect.

I looked around the documentation pubsubclient and tried to grep code base for keywords like `cert, tls, ssl`, but I don't see anything.  Is there some flag I can set to tell pubsubclient to use ssl?

---

**Additional Notes**

This is what my `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` file looks like with SSL

```
port 7382 localhost

listener 7383
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.server.com/fullchain.pem
#cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.server.com/fullchain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.server.com/privkey.pem

allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/logger
```

To disable SSL, I just comment out the `certfile` and `keyfile` lines as well.

Comment: Actually, the SSL version worked for me suddenly.   I think there was an error somewhere else in my code....Anywy, we could close this question...or we could leave it open so people know that pubsubclient can connect over SSL that were signed by public cert authorities.  No extra configuration for pubsubclient.  It works the same as if no ssl.